# wget bash function without messy output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, wget

I am learning to customize `wget` in a `bash` function and having trouble. I would like to display `Downloading (file):%` instead of the messy output of `wget`.  The function below seems close I am having trouble calling it for my specific needs.

For example, my standard `wget` is:

```
cd 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\wget'
wget -O getCSV.txt http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv
```

and that downloads the .csv as a .txt in the directory specified with all the messy `wget` output.

This function seems like it will do more-or-less what I need, but I can not seem to get it to function correctly using my data.  Below is what I have tried. Thank you :).

```
#!/bin/bash
download() {
    local url=$1 wget -O getCSV.txt http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv
    local destin=$2 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\wget'
    echo -n "    "
    if [ "$destin" ]; then
        wget --progress=dot "$url"  -O  "$destin" 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
        sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
    else 
        wget --progress=dot "$url" 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
        sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
    fi
    echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"
    echo " DONE"
}
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash

download () {
url=http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv
destin='C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\wget'
echo -n "    "
if [ "$destin" ]; then
wget -O getCSV.txt --progress=dot "$url"  -O  "$destin" 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
    sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
else 
wget -O getCSV.txt --progress=dot $url 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
fi
echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"
echo " DONE"
menu
}

menu() {
while true
do
    printf "\n Welcome to NGS menu (v1), please make a selection from the MENU \n
    ==================================\n\n
    \t 1  Patient QC\n
    ==================================\n\n"

    printf "\t Your choice: "; read menu_choice

    case "$menu_choice" in
    1) patient ;;
    *) printf "\n Invalid choice."; sleep 2 ;;
    esac
done
}
```

Comment: The line `local url=$1 wget -O getCSV.txt http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv` is confused. What are you trying to do there? That doesn't run that `wget` command. Quote variables when you use them (i.e. `"$url"`, `"$destin"`, etc.)

Comment: What isn't working here exactly? What is happening?

Comment: I quoted the variables and thank you for the edits... maybe I just am unclear but the `wget` in the `local url' is the exact address and the `local destin` is the exact destination to save the file to.

Comment: Are those just supposed to show us the values you are passing in to the function? Are they literally in your script? How are you calling `download`. Because as-written that `wget ...` bit and the destination path are arguments to `local` and are not doing anything useful for you.

Comment: Those are the exact file path and destination that will always be used so maybe I shouldn't be using this function.  I am not sure the best way to call `download`, but I don't think a function is ideal in my case, but I'm not entirely sure how to re-write it to better suit my needs.  Thank you :).

Comment: A function is fine if you need to call it more than once. But then you need to pass the arguments to the function when you call it. `download 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv' 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\wget\getCSV.txt'` or similar. The `$1` and `$2` are the first and second arguments to the function. If you want to hardcode them then you want `local url=http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv` and `local destin='C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\wget\getCSV.txt`.

Comment: Made the changes in the edited code, but no message appears the `bash` just closes after the file downloads.

Comment: As much as I like Bash, is there a specific reason you're not using a higher-level language for this?

Comment: You don't call the `menu` function anywhere but you should see the echo output from the top of the script.

Comment: I made the down load a function and call menu but the `bash` just closes after the download and I have been reading post regarding higher level languages like `python` but need to learn more before I try to use it.  Thank you :).

Comment: Is there still a question after your edits? If yes, please explain what it is. If not, please consider adding at least `[SOLVED]` to your question title.